# Iterate through 'tr' rows in HTML table using WebElement Index in For loop

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to iterate through the rows in a table, pulling the text from the second 'td' of each row and comparing it to the value from a list. Though the index number is counting up, when used as the index number for the 'tr' lines found using 'FindElements', it isn't moving to the next line so it returns the text from the first line every time.

```
List<string> policyList  = parsePolicyTable(driver, pageaction);

int numofPolicies        = policyList.Count();

for (var polListIndex = 0; polListIndex < numofPolicies; polListIndex++)
{
    By polTableBy        = ObjRepository("PolicySearch", "PolicyTable");
    IWebElement polTable = driver.FindElement(polTableBy);

    var rows             = polTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    int rowNum           = rows.Count();

    for (var searchResultRow = 0; searchResultRow < rowNum; searchResultRow++)
    {
        //IWebElement polNumRow  = rows.ElementAt(searchResultRow);
        IWebElement polNumElem = rows[searchResultRow].FindElement(By.XPath("//td[2]"));

        string polNum          = polNumElem.Text;
        string listPolNum      = policyList[polListIndex];

        WritetoLogFile("Policy Number [" + searchResultRow + "] from Search - " + polNum + " | Policy Number [" + polListIndex + "] from List - " + listPolNum);
```

Output:

> Policy Number [0] from Search - XAL0001046-2 | Policy Number [0] from List - XAL0001028-0
>
> Policy Number [1] from Search - XAL0001046-2 | Policy Number [0] from List - XAL0001028-0
>
> Policy Number [2] from Search - XAL0001046-2 | Policy Number [0] from List - XAL0001028-0

I also tried, commented out above, locating the next row using the .ElementAt function with the same result.

What am I missing?

HTML ...

```
      <tr class="odd">
    <td title="Click to select this policy">
      <input type="radio" name="Policy" id="Policy1039" value="1039">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="link8pt cppsInfo" title="XAL0001039-7" data-policynumber="XAL0001039-7">XAL0001039-7</span>
    </td>
    <td title="Policyholder" style="white-space: nowrap;">SHOREY, NORMAND</td>
    <td title="Policyholder Phone Number(s)" style="white-space: nowrap;">(216) 657-7668 (H)</td>
    <td title="Policyholder Address">13675 HIGHWAY 43<br>RUSSELLVILLE, AL 35653-2831</td>
    <td>
      <span class="linkCompact agencyInfo" title="TEST AGENCY #1" data-agencyid="9000">9000-TEST AGENCY #1</span>
    </td>
    <td title="Policy Issue Date">08/31/2018</td>
    <td title="Policy Expiration Date">03/01/2019</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td title="Email Address"></td>
    <td title="Policy Term">6 months paid in full</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td title="Click to select this policy">
      <input type="radio" name="Policy" id="Policy1037" value="1037">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="link8pt cppsInfo" title="XAL0001037-1" data-policynumber="XAL0001037-1">XAL0001037-1</span>
    </td>
    <td title="Policyholder" style="white-space: nowrap;">SMITH, JAMES</td>
    <td title="Policyholder Phone Number(s)" style="white-space: nowrap;">(205) 441-4444 (C)</td>
    <td title="Policyholder Address">100 HUEYTOWN ROAD<br>HUEYTOWN, AL 35023</td>
    <td>
      <span class="linkCompact agencyInfo" title="TEST AGENCY #1" data-agencyid="9000">9000-TEST AGENCY #1</span>
    </td>
    <td title="Policy Issue Date">08/30/2018</td>
    <td title="Policy Expiration Date">03/01/2019</td>
    <td class="xmark" title="This policy has a cancellation notice">X</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td title="Email Address"></td>
    <td title="Policy Term">6 month/5 pay - 17% down</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Post a link to the page or at least post the relevant HTML that you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Outwardly, it looks fine to me, so I'm hazarding a guess. But then I believe FindElements returns a IReadOnlyCollection.

A pure guess, could you try:

```
var rows = polTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).ToList();
```

Really, though, debugging will be your friend here. See what the elements of rows is, etc.